# vba excel View cell but keep formula intact

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, cell

I am using vba with excel to make a user interface what I have is 7 text boxes 6 of the grab the cells m10 - m16 and allow the user to change m17 does exactly the same but my problem is I want to only view m17 and keep the formula everytime I run the program and change a value use 1 of the other 6 boxes it changes the value but removes my formula how can I make it view the result but keep my formula

```
Private Sub nnn()

End Sub

Public Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label12_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label13_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label5_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox12_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox15_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox15.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10").Value
End Sub
```

this is my code but I do not assign the cell in this cod I assign it to text_box4 by right clicking it in the visual editor within excel view properties and enter in as a controlsource

Comment: *how can I make it view the result but keep my formula?*  You can do this by revising your code.  If you want assistance, you're going to have to post the code which you're currently using. We can't read your mind.

Comment: all I have done is use vba then created text boxes then in each text box propertie I just assighn a cell to the control source box

Comment: @PortlandRunner can u give me a link please

Comment: I'm referring to my answer below, not a separate post.  Sorry for the confusion.  Please post your vba code for setting the values and I can help you better.

Comment: @PortlandRunner done a edit above bro but like I say I have no code I just use the visual properties within the vba excel editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are using the `.ControlSource` property of the textbox to pull the values.

[image]

In such a case you cannot prevent the cell from getting over written. The best way to populate the text box is to populate it in the `UserForm_Initialize` event or the `CommandButton1_Click` event

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: okay so I added a teaxt box and added the code above just changed thee A! value and TextBox1 to TextBox15 but nothing appears in the box

Comment: Can you please update your post with the current code that you are using?

Comment: Code looks ok to me. Couple of questions... Are you sure your sheet name is `Sheet1`? Are you sure you have a textbox15? Are you sure that `F10` has a value? Or did you want to use M10 instead of F10?

Comment: when I run the script it just erases all value from the cell so has nothing to display

Comment: You must be clearing of the values of the cell in your script. My code will not clear the cells. Did you clear the `.ControlSource` property of all the textboxes? Also check your code, if something is clearing the cells...

Comment: also everything above is set correctly and like I say f10 has a value until I runf the script and it delets the cell value and formula

Comment: I canoot remove all the control sources I only need this for one cell

Comment: I fixing the cells clearing I did not empty the contolrsoucre for that cell now it just does not display any thing and that is all the code above that's all I have I can save all my exel stuff and send you a copy

Comment: ok upload a copy to any free file sharing service and then upload the link here

Comment: so now I got the values display there are 6 of the boxes where I need to change code how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.Formula
```

Rather than

```
.Value
```

when writing to the cell